# I want to transform part of columns to rows

Tags: sql-server

I have table A

```
mon    start end   tue    start end 
sub009 13:00 14:00 sub004 15:00 15:30 
sub004 14:00 15:00 sub005 15:30 16:00
sub005 15:00 16:00 sub009 16:00 16:30
```

and I am trying to get this

```
13:00  14:00  15:00  15:30  16:00  16:30
mon    sub009 sub004 sub005
tue           sub004 sub005 sub009
```

please I need help

Comment: what version of sql server? (always indicate this!) Is the time range 13:00 to 16:30 fixed? (or is the total range something like 08:00 to 18:00 by 30 minute intervals?) is it always 30 minute intervals?

Comment: Is tableA really only for monday and tuesday? Is that the full set of columns in tableA? (odd looking table)

Comment: Value for mon 15:00 is "sub004" which ends there, but value for tue 15:30 is "sub005" which starts there -- so is it supposed to be according to start or end dates in the other format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have table like this

```
table - monday_schedule
___________________________
Subject |startTime |endTime
___________________________
sub009 13:00 14:00 
sub004 14:00 15:00 
sub005 15:00 16:00
```

And you are plotting the subject names in the end time column, and all times are in interval of 30 min.
Then query like below will help:

```
 select d,[14:00],[14:30],[15:00],[16:00],[16:30]
    from
    (select d,Subject, dayss
    from
    (select 'MON' as d,Subject, startTime, endTime from monday_schedule
    UNION 
    select 'Tue' as d,Subject, startTime, endTime from tuesday_schedule
    ) s
    UNPIVOT
    ( dayss for hourss in ([endTime])  )up)s
    PIVOT
    (
    Max(Subject) for 
    dayss in ([14:00],[14:30],[15:00],[16:00],[16:30])
    )p
```

Sample fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ec0a/3